# Shared Library on Mac with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, shared-libraries

I have a big problem, I can't create a shared library on my Mac with Eclipse.
Everytime I try to compile I get this two 2 Error messages:
make: *** [libOptlist-shared.dylib] Error 1    Optlist-shared          C/C++ Problem
symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 Optlist-shared          C/C++ Problem

I only get the error on Mac. I also tried to create this shared library on Windows and Linux, but there i got no errors.
If anyone can help me, i would be really happy.
Thanks.

Comment: "symbol(s) not found" means that it tries to use functions or global variables that aren't defined anywhere. You need to find that list.

Comment: i forgot to post some additional information which eclipse gives me while building my shared library:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_free", referenced from:
      _FreeOptList in optlist.o
  "_malloc", referenced from:
      _MakeOpt in optlist.o
  "_perror", referenced from:
      _MakeOpt in optlist.o
  "_strlen", referenced from:
      _GetOptList in optlist.o
  "_strrchr", referenced from:
      _RemovePath in optlist.o

For me it seems like the compiler can't find standard functions? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, sounds about right. Are you linking with `-lSystem`?

Comment: No i wasn't linking with `-lSystem`, but i tried it and it seems like that was the problem. Now i have no errors, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't link with libSystem by default, so the linker must explicitly passed `-lSystem`.

Comment: The only thing now is: If I wanna use it, I have to copy the *.dylib file into /usr/lib? Or is there another way?

Comment: You should be able to define an "install path" for the library, and this is where the dynamic linker will expect to find it when it runs your program. The default install path is indeed /usr/lib, I believe.